# User Profile in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which I want to share with other users and so when they run the workbook from their Downloads folder, I want each user to be able to run it. Basically username1 will change for each user.

I tried the examples -> [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091960/userprofile-environ-on-vba)

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub CopyTime()

Dim rFind As Range
Dim rDelete As Range
Dim strSearch As String
Dim iLookAt As Long
Dim bMatchCase As Boolean
Dim WS7 As Worksheet

Const csvFile = "C:\Users\username1\Downloads\Login_Logout_Report.csv"
Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username1\Downloads\ShiftTime.xlsm")
   
   

' Other code goes here
End Sub
```

Here is what I have tried

```
 Const csvFile = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Downloads\Login_Logout_Report.csv"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Downloads\ShiftTime.xlsm")
```

Comment: I got the "constant expression required" error on Environ

Comment: I fixed that and still getting same error "constant expression required"

Comment: Make it `Dim csvFile As String`, `csvFile = ...`. A `Const` must be constant.

Comment: In other words, explained fully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590606/compile-error-constant-expression-required).

Comment: That worked perfect thank you so much!